# typeerror while retriving cookies in web2py

Tags: python, cookies, web2py

```
var websites = new Array("http://www.abc.com","http://www.123.com");
//i am writin cookies like this in javascript in view
var web=websites[1] ;
var exdate=new Date();
exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + 24);
var visit= web +" ;expires= "+ exdate.toUTCString();
document.cookie= "mycookie =" + visit;
```

now while retriving it in controller 
`print request.cookies`
i can see my cookies is there

```
if request.cookies.has_key("mycookie"):#geting true         
value=request.cookies("mycookie").value
```

giving me exception `<type 'exceptions.TypeError'>`

why?

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the full exception? And be sure to indent it 4 spaces so that it appears in the correct format.

Comment: I have given full exception which I am geting.

Comment: It doesn't provide a stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case `request.cookies` is a dictionary, so you must access it as such. As you did:

```
value=request.cookies("mycookie").value
```

This is treating `request.cookies` as a function, which is why you get a TypeError since it is not a function.  To access a value in a dictionary given the key, you can use:

```
value=request.cookies["mycookie"].value
```